# 3 partitions vs 1 partition?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eGQW.png)Hope this is the right place to ask...new to these stackexchange groups...so
Before formatting my pc I had 4 drives C, D and E ..and one more for boot or something.

While installing windows 10 to C drive i got msg that "Windows cannot be installed on this partition....and needs to be formatted with NTFS,...something like this"

So I had to delete all the partitions and format it.
When windows was installed I had 4 Drives..but just one single C drive and three other drives marked as * in minitool partition wizard

What was all this about and how do I go Back to the way i had my drives originally ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your disk has GPT partition style and partitions marked as * are system partitions(UEFI, Recovery and MSR). you need to create partitions by shrinking c drive to create D and E drives. Please share the Minitool Partition Wizard screenshot for better answer.

Comment: Yes I know I can shrink C drive...but I dont want the additional 3 drives marked as *...i want only one like before

Comment: Those partitions are required for system to work and as drive letter is not assigned to those partitions, they won't be appearing in My Computer

Comment: @Zeeshan, read the original question again. These partitions were regular, user-usable storage partitions before reinstalling Windows.

Comment: @Elmo You need at least the ESP - EFI System Partition - in any modern system. Any attempt to install without it may force the whole drive ti be reformatted as MBR and that results in less flexibility and performance and potentially many other issues. Any modern OS should be installed in UEFI mode in UEFI machines. If you don't know what this is you need to educate yourself .

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I am aware of UEFI vs BIOS mode but my pc in 32 bit and Only 64 bit version of Windows can boot from GPT disk and UEFI does support mbr boot also.

Comment: @gronostaj No not user-usable storage partitions , I meant the Recovery, EFI System and Reserved partitions.

Comment: @Zeeshan I know they dont appear in My Computer , but i just want one like I had before...but I am not sure how I can set it up like that again

Comment: @Elmo Please share partition screenshot

Comment: If it 32-bit then it's BIOS (and very old). Do not confuse a 32-bit CPU with a 32-bit UEFI + a 64-bit CPU (early "Bay Trail" generation) in which you'd still be installing a 32-bit Windows in UEFI mode and GPT (or a 64-bit Linux distro). Also yes, the firmware does support both partitioning methods but Windows doesn't: Windows strictly requires GPT for UEFI and MBR for Legacy).

Comment: @Zeeshan shared Screenshot

Comment: @Elmo Partitions are perfectly fine. I guess previously you installed in Legacy BIOS mode that's why it had one system partition, but this time you installed in UEFI mode that creates Recovery partition and EFI partition.

Comment: @Zeeshan so its better to keep UEFI ??

Comment: @Elmo Yes, keep UEFI.